# How to exclude specific path from set_false_path *

Tags: constraints, vivado

I am writing a vivado timing constraints, and in an instance(u_foo), most of its output is false path but only some of them are still need to be constrained.
Is there any way exclude specific path from

`set_false_path  -from [get_cells -hier -filter {NAME =~ */u_foo/o_* }]`

If not, do I have to list all path-wise false path individually?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude specific pins by using && and !~ operators in the filter. Assuming that you want to exclude bar_o output of u_foo instance from the false path constraint. Something like the following can be used:

```
set_false_path -from [get_pins -of_objects [get_cells -hier -filter {NAME =~ *u_foo}] -filter {NAME =~ *o_* && NAME !~ *o_bar*}]
```